# Community without tzitzith

Tags: minhag, tzitzis, tallit-gadol, mesorah-tradition, tallit-katan

Are/were there any halachic Jewish communities that do/did not have a daily custom of wearing a garment obligated in *tzitzith* (e.g. *tallith katan*/*tallith gadol*)?

Comment: It was common for the Italian Jewish community to not wear tzitzit or have a beard. For example, Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzatto did not have either tzitzit or a beard. See [this](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2011/01/beards-and-beardlessness-in-italian.html) blogpost from one of my favorite Jewish blogs, "On the Main Line."

Comment: The ר"י in says that it wasn't the minhag (connected to the problem of leog la raash), bought down I think in niddah, and mentioned by the Beis Yosef in hilchos Aveilus. I don't have the time to find it now, but if anyone wants to type it up...

Answer (score 5):

Rabbenu Avraham ben HaRambam implies (HaMaspik L'Ovdei Hashem, ed. Wincelberg p. 27) that in his place and time it was not common to wear a four cornered garment with tsitsit.

He is giving examples of behaviours that a person may inappropriately perform just in order to be perceived as pious, and he includes wearing tsitsit constantly. He includes this in the Sages description of *yuhara* arrogant expressions of excessive religious activity, (Berakhot 17b, Pesahim 55a).

This strongly indicates that wearing a four cornered garment with tsitsit on it was not common there.

[Rambam's encouragement](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82982/8775) that pious people wear tsitsit complements this, (although does not prove it).

Answer (score 3):

[R. Eliezer ben Nathan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_ben_Nathan) has a responsum ([Sefer Ra'avan siman 40](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14544&st=&pgnum=71)) in which the question posed was, "why do the majority of Jews not wear tzitzit on a daily basis?"

> שאלני חתני רבי אורי מצוה חמודה כמו ציצית שהיא שקולה כנגד כל המצות מאי
>   שנא דמקילין בה רוב ישראל שאין מתעטפין בכל יום

This indicates that the widespread custom at the time was to not wear tzitzit on a daily basis.