# Car wash during the 9 days?

Tags: halacha, nine-days

Is it allowed to wash one's car during the 9 days?

Or is it like clothing, since it is also for show and it surrounds you?

Comment: Where is washing a non-porous object ever called כיבוס?

Comment: @DoubleAA i do not claim it is , so a car will be like leather clothing (which i do not know what the law is)

Comment: הבו דלא לוסיף עליה

Answer (score 5):

[Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmuel_Kamenetsky) writes in Kovetz Halachos Bein HaMeitzarim (8:4-5) that cleaning the car would be permitted during the Nine Days (with certain fabric exceptions), but "body work" on the outside of the car would be an issue.

[image]

Also, [Halachically Speaking](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol15Issue8.pdf) (15:8:n.1) says "A car wash is permitted during the nine days" based on Rav Elyashiv (Ashrei Haish O.C. 3, page 475:65) and the Natei Gavriel Bein Hamitzarim (29:19).

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.shaaray-tefilah.org/weekly/halachos.pdf) says that one may wash his car and polish silver, but not shampoo the rug. It does not give a reason. Then, again, I would assume regarding Nine Days that [if something is not specifically mentioned as being forbidden, then it's permitted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89916/5275). Kudos to Alex for the M.Y. link.