# Position on young women working

Tags: halacha, minhag, talmud-gemara, women

Are unmarried Jewish women allowed to work? (Volunteer or not volunteer, paid or unpaid) Why or why not? Please provide your sources accordingly. Please also provide which sects (if they are multiple sects) follows these rules and which sect (if they are multiple) does not. I would please like the “Traditional Orthodox” (to use a phrase from the RAA: https://rabbinicalalliance.org/)
opinion. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: In all sects, women (married and unmarried) work and volunteer. The why is to support themselves and their families or volunteer for good causes.

Comment: Why would a permissive answer need a source, since you haven't provided any reason to forbid? You might as well be asking "is it permitted for unmarried women to stand on one foot for 7 seconds when they want to".

Comment: @magicker72 Indeed: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89916/if-something-is-not-explicitly-prohibited-is-it-permitted

Comment: There is a concept of Kol Kevoda Bas Melech Pnima. The gemarah frowns upon one who makes his wife go out to the street to sell things to make money. However, the main idea behind it is not to do things that stand out. Since nowadays it's commonplace for women to work, it's no longer considered standing out and nobody seems to say there's an issue with it anymore

Comment: Do you mean to ask "under what circumstances may an unmarried Jewish woman work"?

Answer (score 1):

[Rav Avigdor Miller on the Well-Paying Dangerous Job](https://torasavigdor.org/rav-avigdor-miller-on-the-well-paying-dangerous-job/)

**Q**:
If a girl is offered a well-paying job in a gentile company, can she take it?

**A**:
It depends on the circumstances. Are there enough frum workers around her? Will she be subject to the influence of the males of low character who work there and are around her? How much does she need the job? Without knowing the answers to these questions – and other questions as well – nobody can give you a true answer. Without knowing the girl and having an understanding of these factors, I couldn’t tell you.

This needs special private instruction from people who know her well and know the circumstances. פרנסה is very important, but a job like that can easily ruin a woman. And therefore, it needs thoughtful deliberation by someone who knows the girl.

TAPE #E-169

Comment: These considerations apply to a man just as much.

Comment: @N.T. Partially true, but I think that women are more likely to get hit on by crude slimy males, rather than a gentile woman trying to flirt with a yeshiva guy.

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question than the one asked. No one should take a dangerous job (and what is dangerous will obviously depend on the person). - But this answer itself takes for granted that this same girl is allowed to take a *non*-dangerous job.

Comment: @MichoelR Rabbi Miller's Q & A were transcribed verbatim from the recordings of his lectures, so you can see the exact question the rabbi was asked. The titles for these Q & A are from the editors, who look for catchy lines to attract the reader's attention. The point they're trying to convey is, that what might look like a bland mundane job, can really be very dangerous; from a religious perspective.

Comment: But as @MichoelR said, the question was whether unmarried girls can work period. To say that some jobs are risky is not an answer to the question as asked.

Comment: @N.T. Rabbi Miller's position is nuanced. He clearly would allow unmarried Jewish girls to work. However depending on the circumstances, not every job is considered suitable for a Jewish young woman.

Comment: @IsraelReader The question did not ask for this nuance though.

Comment: @N.T. I think that my answer was relevant, but we can agree to disagree. Go ahead and down-vote, if that makes you feel better.

Comment: @IsraelReader Already did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unmarried women are absolutely allowed to work. This is obvious to the point that it does not have to be stated. The [Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.43a.15?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&p2=Mishneh_Torah%2C_Marriage.19.10&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) does say that until age 12, the earnings belong to her father. But after age 12 or if her father dies, she can keep the earnings for herself, even if the brothers support her.