# Murder in Eretz Yisrael

Tags: mitzvah, eretz-yisrael, sin, murder

The Gemara in Yoma (85a) argues that murder is more *chamur* than *chilul Shabbos* because it "contaminates the land and drives away the *Shechina*"

> ושפיכות דמים מטמא את הארץ וגורם לשכינה שתסתלק מישראל

This is based on the pasuk in Bamidbar 35:33-34 which says:

> ולא־תחניפו את־הארץ אשר אתם בה כי הדם הוא יחניף את־הארץ ולארץ לא־יכפר לדם אשר שפך־בה כי־אם בדם שפכו
>
> ולא תטמא את־הארץ אשר אתם ישבים בה אשר אני שכן בתוכה
> כי אני יהוה שכן בתוך בני ישראל

Does this mean that commiting murder within Eretz Yisrael is even more *chamur* than doing so outside the Land?

Even if we argue that the driving away of the *Shechina* applies to Jews everywhere, the contamination of the Land appears to be Eretz Yisrael specific.

Comment: This could be related to Eglah Arufah only applying in Israel